# Array filter by date range

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Hi I would like to filter my data between date ranges.

```
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000004",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 9,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000005",
    "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 5
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 10,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000008",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100,
    "missedChats": 50
}
```

My current implementation

```js
function getData(start, end) {
  if (start == null && end == null) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {

        console.log(
          Object.values(
            data.reduce((acc, el) => {
              if (!(el.websiteId in acc)) {
                acc[el.websiteId] = el;
              } else {
                acc[el.websiteId].chats += el.chats;
                acc[el.websiteId].missedChats += el.missedChats;
              }
              return acc;
            }, {})
          )
        );
      });
  } else {
    var start = new Date('2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z').getTime();
    var end = new Date('2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z').getTime();

    result = data.filter((d) => {
      var time = new Date(d.date).getTime();
      return start < time && time < end;
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

Expected Output

when I run getData(startDate(2019-4-01), endDate(2019-4-02))
I should be able to get the data between those date range

```
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100,
    "missedChats": 2
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 110,
    "missedChats": 50
}
```

I would like to get data between the range of date when I run the function getDate(startDate, endDate)

Comment: `data.map(result => {})` has no effect, so not sure why you have that there. Also, `data` in the `if` seems to come from the API call but in the `else`, where is `data` declared/assigned? In other words, your if and else are doing completely different and seeming unrelated things.

Comment: sorry, forgot to remove my map. edited my question.

Comment: Your function has `start` and `end` as parameters, but then they are redeclared as `const` symbols in the `else` part. The parameters are ignored.

Comment: sorry, I didn't saw that part. edited my question

Comment: Your `start` and `end` dates are invalid: you are missing a leading `0` in the day part of the date. Also, the `end` timestamp is actually before the `start` timestamp: a typo perhaps?

Comment: return data.filter(data => {
        var start = new Date('2019-04-01').getTime();
        var end = new Date('2019-04-02').getTime();
        const dateTime  = new Date(data.date).getTime();

        return dateTime >= start && dateTime <= end;

where should I put this line from the answer below

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that invalidates valid answers. Ask a new question. Stackoverflow is a Q&A platform with specific programming questions to help future user with similar problems. If you change the question it's unclear how the answers solved which problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the if condition into the `.then` block:

```js
const data = [{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000004",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 9,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000005",
    "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 5
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 10,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000008",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100,
    "missedChats": 50
}];

function getData(start, end) {
  /*fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {*/
      const summedData =
        Object.values(
          data.reduce((acc, el) => {
            if (!(el.websiteId in acc)) {
              acc[el.websiteId] = el;
            } else {
              acc[el.websiteId].chats += el.chats;
              acc[el.websiteId].missedChats += el.missedChats;
            }
            return acc;
          }, {}));
      if (start && end) {
        result = summedData.filter((d) => {
          const time = new Date(d.date).getTime();
          return start < time && time < end;
        });
        console.log(result);
      } else {
        console.log(summedData);
      }
    /*});*/
}

const start = new Date('2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z').getTime();
const end = new Date('2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z').getTime();

getData(start, end);
getData();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting result is not defined.

Comment: @PinkyPromise As you can see with "Run code snippet" it works. That could mean that the fetched and parsed data is different to the data you posted.

Comment: yes I'm fetching the data through an api but the result variable is undefined.

Comment: @PinkyPromise I can't help without more details. You provided example data and with the example data it works. I can't help with data you didn't provide.

Comment: I got it working now. but also I want to sum the total chats and missedchats per websiteID when I filter with date range.

Comment: Hi, one last question. I removed the if else statement but it gives me 2 array

Comment: You have two `console.log` statements. Therefore you have two outputs.

Comment: I tried the summedData it returns me an empty array.

Comment: @PinkyPromise Have you tried to click the "Run code snippet" button? If my code works and your code doesn't work there are differences between our codes. Without showing me your code I can't help. I only know the code and data in your question and I created a working solution with this information.

Comment: @PinkyPromise I rolled the changes back.

Comment: sorry my fault for changing the question.

Comment: @PinkyPromise It's important to understand the difference between Stackoverflow and a forum. The goal isn't to help a single user but to build a knowledge base like a wiki to help many users.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, your `filter` method is correct, you should convert your date strings into a `Date` and compare with `getTime`.

```js
const data = [{
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 121,
  "missedChats": 0
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 13,
  "missedChats": 0
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 232,
  "missedChats": 9
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000004",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 9,
  "missedChats": 0
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000005",
  "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 0,
  "missedChats": 5
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
  "date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 10,
  "missedChats": 0
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 100,
  "missedChats": 1
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000008",
  "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 0,
  "missedChats": 0
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
  "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 0,
  "missedChats": 1
}, {
  "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
  "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "chats": 100,
  "missedChats": 50
}];

function getData(start, end) {
  const startTime = new Date(start).getTime();
  const endTime = new Date(end).getTime();

  return data.filter(item => {
    const itemTime = new Date(item.date).getTime();

    return itemTime >= startTime && itemTime <= endTime;
  })
}

console.log(getData('2019-04-01', '2019-04-02'))
```

Comment: should I put it on top of my Object.values? can't make it work.

Comment: I'm getting start is not defined.

Comment: Where? my code snippet is runnable, and it runs :]

Comment: in my current code I can't implement it. on the question above.